# NULL NOT NULL on Default constraint in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

If I set a Record in Sql with a `Default` constraint like

```
[Publicbit]   BIT             DEFAULT ((0)),
```

Do I need to set the `NULL/NOTNULL` Constraint?

**Edit:** I am using a boolean but please expand your answer to other datatypes.

Comment: @marc_s Guessing SQL Server given the brackets and `BIT` type.

Comment: @marc_s thanks for the reply I am using MSSQL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You never *need* the Null constraints, but the default value won't guard your table against explicit NULL's. So you should use a NOT NULL constraint if you want to enforce this condition.

```
use tempdb
go
CREATE TABLE example
(
    id BIT DEFAULT (0)
)

INSERT example (id) VALUES (null)

SELECT * FROM example
```

Comment: Hint: I would always recommend to **explicitly name** your (default) constraints: `id BIT CONSTRAINT DF_Example_ID DEFAULT (0)` so that you'll have an well-known **name** for your constraint if you ever need to disable and/or drop it.

Answer (score 3):

You should specify NOT NULL, to protect against a NULL from getting into this record.  It sounds like the only valid values you want are 0 and 1.  If someone (or you in the future) writes a record (or code) passing in a NULL for this column, then it will be allowed unless you specified NOT NULL.

By specifying a DEFAULT, you are only protecting against a NULL value if the SQL INSERT statement doesn't include that column.

Answer (score 2):

No, they are optional.

```
column_name 
    ...
    [ NULL | NOT NULL ]
```

You shouldn't expect a `NULL` when your options are `0/1`.

Comment: what about other datatypes such as NVARCHAR and Ints?

Comment: @FloodGravemind It depends on your data requirements. I don't want to say there's a general rule, but given that those attributes are *optional* then I suggest that you don't need these attributes.

Answer (score 1):

These are just optional. It is up to you if you want to specify it or not

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187742.aspx):

> Determines whether null values are allowed in the column. NULL is not
>   strictly a constraint but can be specified just like NOT NULL.